# Why would I want matzah made from flour that was ground in a hand-mill?

Tags: matzah, hands-fingers

I saw an advertisement for a matzah-baking group. Part of the advertisement claimed, in big, ostentatious letters, that the flour was "רחים של יד" -- presumably because they wanted you know that the flour was milled by hand.

Why should I care? Is there any reason I should prefer hand-ground flour for my matzah, rather than flour that was ground by a water-mill or by a machine?

Answer (score 4):

I assume they are also claiming to grind it *lishma* (with the intention that it will be used for the *mitzvah*) and that it's not as simple to rely on *lishma* by machine-made as by hand (as with regard to the remaining *matzoh*-making processes and [printing *sifrei torah*](http://etzion.org.il/vbm/english/archive/mb/89mb.htm)).

> ...matzah shemurah must be prepared with the intention of fulfilling the mitzvah of achilat matzah. This means that if the cutting, ***grinding***, kneading and baking of the matzah were done without the proper kavanah (intention), then the resulting product may not be used to fulfill the mitzvah at the seder.
>
> This brings us to the primary objection against machine matzah: Matzah
> shemurah needs to be made by committed Jews who have the proper
> kavanah, and a machine could obviously have no such kavanah. The
> defenders of the machine asserted that a machine was a tool, no
> different than a rolling pin, and therefore, it sufficed if the Jew
> operating the machine had the correct kavanah.
>
> By the beginning of the twentieth century, virtually the entire
> non-Chassidic world accepted the use of machine matzah peshutah for
> the eight days of Passover. Most Chassidim continued to disagree. The
> debate about using machine matzah shemurah at the seder continues
> until the present day.

(from:[Rabbi Shmuel Singer at OU.org](https://www.ou.org/news/the_great_matzah_controversy_should_matzah_be_made_by_hand_or_machine/); see there for a more complete discussion of the history of the machine vs. hand-matzah controversy; ; see also: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/796575/Rabbi_Chaim_Eisenstein/Halacha_from_the_Daily_Daf:_Pesachim_40--Defining_Matzah_Shmurah_&_Is_the_New_%27Hiddur%27_of_Hand_Ground_Matzahs_Really_a_Hiddur#)

Comment: I don't see any mention of Grinding-Lishma in Shulchan Aruch (http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_29.html#HtmpReportNum0024_L2)